# pyodbc TypeError with Unicode connection string

Tags: python, typeerror, connect, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server database with the following code:

```
import pyodbc
path = 'DRIVER=(SQL Server); SERVER = СВЕТЛАНА-ПК\SQLEXPRESS; DATABASE = test_db; UID = sveta; PWD = 1111'
connect = pyodbc.connect(path)
```

and I receive this error:

> TypeError: A Unicode connection string was supplied but the driver does not have a Unicode connect function

Can you please help me?

Comment: Can you please format your question?

Comment: Unicode characters aren't supported by that library. `СВЕТЛАНА-ПК` looks problematic

Comment: but according to thin manual [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tTjbIwzZ0Yk) it should not be problem

Answer (score 1):

I was able to recreate your issue when using

```
DRIVER=(SQL Server)
```

in the connection string. When I changed it to use braces `{}` instead of parentheses `()` ...

```
DRIVER={SQL Server}
```

... the error went away.